# Verify H2 Backup is not corrupted

Tags: h2

I am developing an H2 (TCP), based application and I created a feature that takes a backup file when a button is clicked.

I used the

```
BACKUP TO '<FILENAME>'
```

command to take online backups. I had tested it and it works, but for very rare instances, the backup is corrupted.

Is there any API in H2 to check if the backup file is corrupted? I am thinking I would load that backup zip file, then do count queries on all tables and display it on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas (creator of H2) citiated before fastest way to verify is getting connection. If you want to learn if the data is corrupted, Backup and Restore is the another encouraged way. Currently There isn't any api or tool now.

From Thomas:

```
There is a small risk that the database file exists, but not fully initialized. If that is the case,
then some of the tables don't exist. The standard way to verify all tables exists is to us
DatabaseMetaData.getTables.
```

Comment: if I have ~DB1 backup, can I restore it to ~DB2 for verification?

Comment: I don't really understand your requirements? Do you want to backup and restore your DB1.mv.db to DB2.mv.db?

Comment: Ok, so I've been burned by trusting my backup file before. When I did the BACKUP TO command, and some user deleted the wrong data. I thought just restore the old version. By overwriting the current db with the one on the backup zip file. However, when I loaded blanks were loaded. So, since you mentioned the only was is to do a backup and restore, if I did that, and the backup I generated was corrupted, I would be restoring the bad file. And I won't be able to recover. So I need to check the backup integrity on a separate DB name so if it is corrupted, it won't damage the current data.